# What does the apt-get -f install do?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

I'm a total rookey in linux, so please I have a question, after reading a tutorial I learned how to install .deb archives using the terminal,so installed Play On Linux, then I tried to install wine:i386 using "sudo apt-get wine:i386" but the terminal didn't donwload the package, instead tells me to use the command sudo apt-get -f install, I want to know what means that -f.

A complete thanks for the person that can answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get -f Attempts to correct a system with broken dependencies in place